# Tomcat Host & port Configuration

Tags: tomcat, redirect, port, hostname

I have tomcat 5.5 in my windows environment listening to the port:8080.I wanted to change the hostname from localhost to www.mydomain.com.Adding the alias name in the conf/server.xml & adding the entry in /etc/hosts file I achieved this.But I have to access the name with the port number in the URL like http://www.mydomain.com:8080/ .Is there any way with out specifying the port number in the URL, redirect/forward the requests to port 8080 if the URL is www.mydomain.com?

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to change this in [tomcat home]/conf/server.xml (at least on a unix-type system, but should be similar on win). search for 8080 and change it there.

Answer (score 0):

YOu shoul dfind the following line in server.xml

`<Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
               enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />`

change `port="8080"` to `port="80"`

Unless you already have something on port 80 of course.

Comment: Yes.It worked.Thanks.But Can I know where the default port (80) configuration is defined since I am not giving any port number there?

Comment: Port 80 is the standard http port that a web browser will look at by default. So when you type www.google.com into a web browser, it uses port 80.